# Material-UI - Tooltip staying open on hover with a nested popover

Tags: material-ui

I'm having problems creating a hoverable tooltip. The tooltip should have a button in it that can be used to open a popover. The problem I have is that once I open the popover it closes the tooltip. The popover is also displayed behind the tooltip.

```
<Tooltip
    interactive
    title={<Content />}
    placement="right-start"
>
```

Content:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-owns={open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        variant="contained"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
      >
          The content of the PopoverThe content of the the Popover.The content of the PopoverThe content of the the Popover.The content of the PopoverThe content of the the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT: created a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6w26o2ww0z

Comment: Please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces the problem and include its link in your question. This will make it much easier for others to experiment with and verify potential solutions.

Comment: HI I created a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6w26o2ww0z

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't display anything other than the default CodeSandbox message. Please edit the sandbox so that it **reproduces** the problem.